# Redirect visitors to the new pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a new version of my website but the new urls are completely different. The old ones are like /some-page-3.html and the new ones are like /article/index/5, and there is no association between the id.

I would like to redirect the visitors to the new pages, when somebody is coming from google on /some-page-3.html then redirect him to article/index/5. I really need this even if I have to write one line for every page in the htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to redirect everything to the main file (controller) and handle the redirect internally in your code (this is called bootstrapping)

If you want to do it with mod_rewrite use thin

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some-page-3.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /article/index/5 [QSA,L]
```

ps the above won't work with trailing slashes, to enabled those use `^/some-page-3.html[/]?$ [NC]`

Comment: I don't get it why is not working, it just continues to redirect to 404. The new website is built with codeignitere.